# Importing multiple vector data file

Tags: plotting

```
 I have 30 data file (data1.txt,data2.txt .....data30.txt) at different 
   time(t1, t2,...t30) with six component (x,y,z, Ex,Ey,Ez) each data file. How 
   to import this data file using a single "Import" and plot it.
     I am trying using a given code:
      d1 = Import["D:\\field data\\f0 (1).txt", "Table"];
      d2 = Import["D:\\field data\\f0 (2).txt", "Table"];
      d3 = Import["D:\\field data\\f0 (3).txt", "Table"];
       data1 = d1[[4 ;; 10]]; data2 = d2[[4 ;; 10]]; data3 = d3[[4 ;; 10]];
       ListContourPlot3D[{data1, data2, data3}]
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Nasser, I want to use just single "Import"  commond, because I have 30 data  data file.

Comment: You cannot. `Import` can only import one file. You will have to import all the files using `Map` over the list of filenames. Then combine the results from each import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, the simplest way is following:

```
SetDirectory["D:\\field data\\"];
fn=FileNames["f0*.txt"];
data=Table[Import[f,"Table"][[4;;10]],{f,fn}];
```

You can use the data as you wish..

Comment: Is it possible to animate the data, which means I want to see changes in time. (here  data files at a different time)? I have added the data file and plot expected t some time.

Comment: @GopalVerma, Do you mean to see the actual file list in the directory?  Or the currently loaded file?

Comment: I am trying to plot data files one by one  just like in animation. You can see expected plot(at some time) in my updated question.

Comment: If you wish the slide-show from different files, than you need wrapping your plotting command by the `Manipulate[ListContourPlot[data[[i]]], {i,1,Length@data,1}]`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use just single "Import" commond, because I have 30 data
>   data file

I do not see the need to use one import command.

Why not just use a loop? See if this does what you want. (Not tested)

```
fileName0 = "D:\\field data\\f0 (";
numOfFiles = 30;
data = Table[0, {numOfFiles}];

Do[
  fileName = fileName0 <> ToString[n] <> ").txt";
  tmp = Import[fileName, "Table"];
  data[[n]] = tmp[[4 ;; 10]],
  {n, 1, numOfFiles}
  ];

(*Now process data as needed*)
```

ps. it is not a good idea to have spaces in file names.